# How to call service from service callback

Tags: java, android

I have a java background serviceA and serviceB. I have instantiated serviceA in onStart method in Mainactivity class . I need to start serviceB if the serviceA fails to start. I have written a callback method which gets called in MainActivity but when I tried to call serviceB it is not getting created.

I have written a callback method in MainActivity which gets called in serviceA but when I tried to call serviceB it is not getting created.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ServiceCallbacks{
         private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
         private Context myContext = null;

         Intent myTestService;
         private MyTestService serviceA;
         private boolean bound = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate called.");       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(serviceA == null) {
            serviceA = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);
            Log.d(TAG,"onResume called.");
            Log.d(TAG,"myTestService instance created.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG,"onPause called.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Log.d(TAG,"OnDestory called");
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // bind to Service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from service
        if (bound) {
            myService.setCallbacks(null); // unregister
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            bound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // cast the IBinder and get MyService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
            myService.setCallbacks(MainActivity.this); // register
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            bound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void callBackToActivity() {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        StartNewService();
    }

    private void StartNewService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, serviceB.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

I want to start serviceB if serviceA fails to start.
I am c# developer and new to java and need your help.

Comment: I want to unbind the existing service which already started and start new service.

Comment: my requirement is to have one java service installer and should able to start backup service incase first one fails.

Comment: serviceA and serviceB uses different jars so I want to keep them separate.

Comment: I am not sure, but did you try `transient`? like `private transient boolean bound = false;`